# openssl ruby 1.9.3 and nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

In nodejs I can use crypto to do these function:

```
var equal = function(value, tag) {
var expected = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(value).digest('hex'),
  actual    = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(tag).digest('hex');
 return expected === actual;
```

}

How can I do the same using ruby 1.9.3 openssl library  or any other library?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the OpenSSL bindings like this:

```
require 'openssl'
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new
hex_digest = digest.update("value").hexdigest
```

You can also use the digest/sha1 library (if you're on a Ruby runtime that doesn't support the OpenSSL bindings or you just don't want to use them)

```
require 'digest/sha1'
digest = Digest::SHA1.new
hex_digest = digest.update("value").hexdigest
```

Comment: Well, the examples just build hexdigests. You can trivially adapt it to build that equality function though.